# Flutter Scaffold Code suddenly starts to give me error

Tags: flutter, dart, build, compiler-errors

My code keeps giving me error due to return Scaffold.
here is my scaffold code:

```
 class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {   @override   Widget
 build(BuildContext context) {
     
return Scaffold(
       
         drawer: Drawer(
            child: Column
            (children: <Widget>[
              AppBar(automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
         title: Text('Special Options'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent.shade400
         ),
```

Here is the error code I got during debug

> Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
> lib/ui/usertype.dart:29:24: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
>
> file:///C:/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
> Compiler failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yiu probably accidentally modified Flutter source code.

You can check by running in your Flutter install dir

```
git status
```

It should report no modifications

To fix run in your Flutter install dir

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but after doing that I got errors. what I got from pubspec       
         :Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\font_awesome_flutter-8.2.0".

Comment: Thanks error cleared by running flutter pub pub cache repair

Comment: Scaffold error suddenly popped up again yesterday, tried the solution over and over again but not working

Comment: Not to sure but its only given me scaffold error :  Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
    return Scaffold(

Comment: Do you have more than one Flutter installation on your system? Is the IDE Plugin config pointing to the correct one?

Comment: I have only one flutter installation and it's pointing to the right destination. It still worked well some days ago but yesterday scaffold started  misbehaving again

Comment: Can't imagine this being anything else than a corrupted Flutter setup. Try running `git status` in the Flutter install dir and add the output to your question. To be sure you can try `flutter clean` and then run again or perhaps manually uninstall the app from device/emulator.

Comment: Thanks for helping me all through. I really appreciate your effort switching to a stable version then following your steps over again did the magic